# Apply Where clause in eager loading in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, laravel-5, eager-loading

I have two table in my database:

1. *tbl_patient_master*
2. *tbl_dept_master*

Columns of the **tbl_patient_master** table are:

- patient_id
- patient_name
- dept_id
- created_at
- updated_at

Columns of the **tbl_dept_master** table are:

- dept_id
- dept_name
- dept_type

Now I'd like to show a list of patients of a specific **Department**. If the user says 'ENT' then all patients with 'ENT' dept should be returned.

For this I have created the following relationship in my model.

```
public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Entities\Department','dept_id'); 
}
```

and this code to fetch data in my controller:

```
$patients = $this->repository->with(array('department' => function ($query) use ($dept_name)
{
     $query->where('dept_name', '=', $dept_name);
}))->all();
```

Unfortunately this will return all patients not just the ones from a specific dept.
What should I do to get all patients from a specific department?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it from the `Patient` model perspective, you can opt for using a `whereHas`.

```
$dept_name = Input::get('dept_name');

$patients = Patient::whereHas('department', function ($query) use ($dept_name) {
    $query->where('dept_name', '=', $dept_name);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use *repository*, just use the **Patient** model.
You have defined the association, so this should work:

```
App\Patient::where('dept_name', '=', 'ENT');
```

Comment: Thanks, BTWI have used Repository method all over my project, so i dont want to change flow and structure.